# In what case would a file won't upload from Android to aws S3

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm trying to upload an image to AWS S3 from my Android. The problem is that when I run this code, it doesn't show me any errors but the file is still not uploaded to the S3. I used this guide to try to upload my images
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/mobile/sdkforandroid/developerguide/s3transferutility.html
but it doesn't seem to work. What could be the case of it not uploading?

```
            new Thread() {
                @Override
                public void run() {

                    // Initialize the Amazon Cognito credentials provider
                    CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider credentialsProvider = new CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider(
                            getApplicationContext(),
                            "us-east-1:????????????????d", // Identity Pool ID
                            Regions.US_EAST_1 // Region
                    );


                    // Instantiate an S3 Client
                    // Create an S3 client
                    AmazonS3 s3 = new AmazonS3Client(credentialsProvider);

                    // Set the region of your s3 bucket
                    s3.setRegion(Region.getRegion(Regions.DEFAULT_REGION));

                    // Instantiate TransferUtility
                    TransferUtility transferUtility = new TransferUtility(s3, getApplicationContext());

                    //Upload a file to amazon s3

                    Log.i("imageFile", imageFile.toString());
                    TransferObserver observer = transferUtility.upload(
                            "foond",     /* The bucket to upload to */
                            "key",    /* The key for the uploaded object */
                            imageFile        /* The file where the data to upload exists */
                    );
                }
            }.start();
```

Also, just in case someone asks, The file is not null. I've already initialized it. When I log the imageFile, it prints 
I/imageFile: /storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/IMG_20160223_134442.jpg

Also, it should be noted that I had to select my location to be N. Virginia when I'm from California if that makes any difference. I had to make it in another region because cognito was not available in my area.

Comment: What version of the AWS SDK are you using? Can you check the observer to see if any data is being uploaded? What state is it in? Can you read a little bit of the image via stream to ensure it has permissions to be read?

Comment: Hi, I fixed my problem. I just had to change (Regions.DEFAULT_REGION) US_EAST_1.